# Kotlin - How to increase value of mutableMap

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I wanna add 1 to a particular item value of mutableMap in Kotlin laguage.
Below is what I made.
Is there any way to make this code simple?

```
map[1] = map[1]?.let {it -> it + 1 } ?: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use [**getOrDefault**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get-or-default.html):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val map = mutableMapOf(1 to 0, 2 to 0)
    println("Before: " + map)
    map[1] = map.getOrDefault(1, 0) + 1
    println("After: " +  map)
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before: {1=0, 2=0}
After: {1=1, 2=0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify that a little by doing the addition after handling the null:

```
map[1] = (map[1] ?: 0) + 1
```

If you're doing that a lot, you could add it as an extension function, e.g.:

```
fun <T> MutableMap<T, Int>.increment(key: T, defaultValue: Int = 0) {
    this[key] = (this[key] ?: defaultValue) + 1
}
```

(That version also lets you specify a different default value if you want.)

You could call that like:

```
map.increment(1)
```

You could extend that to add or subtract numbers other than 1.  (Though in that case, you'd probably want to change the function name.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a nice clean way of doing this, because we always have to handle the case that the key does not exist somehow.

You could use [`Map.merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) from the JDK. This will add a new key with value `1` if it doesn't already exist.

```
map.merge(1, 1, Int::plus)
```

That doesn't feel very idomatic though. So you could wrap it in an extention function:

```
fun MutableMap<Int, Int>.increment(key: Int) = merge(key, 1, Int::plus)
```

Example:

```
fun main() {
    val map = mutableMapOf(1 to 1)
    map.merge(1, 1, Int::plus)
    println(map)
    map.increment(1)
    println(map)
    map.increment(2)
    println(map)
}
```

Output:

```
{1=2}
{1=3}
{1=3, 2=1}
```